# How does backend interaction work in an app like iOS Activity app where there is multiple days of data to be shown to the user?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui, backend

I have an app that collects user data for a time through an external device and then saves it to a backend. The app, once the user logs in, fetches that data from the backend and shows it to the user.

The User can swipe to switch between days, or weeks, months. 
It has the functionality similar to the Activity app or a Calendar App.

The backend unit of data is for a day. For example, a months data will have 30 JSON objects for each day.

What is the right approach to get the data in the app from the backend.?

I was thinking of 2 approaches.

1. When the user swipes, fetch the data from the backend. 
   I was also thinking of having some threshold, for example, if a user scroll/swipes beyond a certain day the next block of days will be fetched.
2. Save the data locally. 
   The idea here is that the app will fetch and store the data in Core Data, then the app pulls the data from the local store and shows it to the user. I am not sure about this as this will keep taking a lot of storage on the phone.

I think it has some relation to infinite scroll apps, but in this case the data available is from the previous days.

I don't know what the correct technical terms are to describe this, I stumbled upon some posts where the word "pagination" was mentioned.

What I would like to know is how to approach the development of this. 
1. How frequently the API calls need to happen to the backend?
2. Is it necessary to store this data in Core Data?
3. When should the API calls happen to fetch the data so the app feels responsive?

Answer (score 1):

How and whether to cache your data and how and when to update that cache is actually a complicated question and it depends on a lot of things, such as how quickly your data changes and how expensive it is to retrieve.  Many technologies exist to solve this problem for you by giving you eventual consistency and updates from the server (ie firebase or a graphQL watch).  If you want to implement it manually it sounds like in your case the data gets uploaded once and never changes.  In such a case, its pretty straight forward to say that you should probably cache it locally and only fetch it when its missing (ie you log into a new device).  that's pretty easy to do:

1. When you display data check if you are n items or fewer away from the last item in the list and if the server has more data and if you re not currently loading.  If so fetch more items and set isLoading to true.
2. If you got more items, update your cache and display, set isLoading to false.  If you didn't get more items because the server said there are none then set has more data to false and set isLoading to false.

Comment: Hi Josh, Thanks for the reply. 

The data doesn't change for previous days, for the current day, the data might change every hour. We have an existing django backend ready to receive API requests. Still defining how we want to fetch the data. For example, whether to give a date range as a parameter to receive an array of data for each day.  Assuming Core Data is my Local cache. is the right approach then to having a sync mechanism between backend and local cache and then the view only gets the data from the local cache?

Comment: In a use case like this, is the data fetched one day at a time, or in blocks for multiple days?

Comment: You absolutely want to have a date range (or a start record and a count) so you can easily change the page size later.  The cache is always the source of truth; ie you have a fetchedResultsController that subscribes to the cache and when the api call comes back it updates the cache so the viewController (or viewModel) updates the tableView automatically.  You need to discuss with the backend team what the idea page size is.  If the payload is quite small it may make sense to fetch many days at once.  Your pagination logic is the same no matter the page size, so you can always change it later.